# High-quality open-source street view panoramas

Tags: google-street-view, mapillary, panorama

We need ~1000 high-quality panorama street view images with location that can be downloaded and used as part of an open-source project. The ideal dataset would be [Google Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview), but their API severely limits its use and our project does not fulfil [the restrictions](https://about.google/brand-resource-center/products-and-services/geo-guidelines/).

[Mapillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapillary) and [KartaView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KartaView) (formerly OpenStreetCam) both have 360-degrees panorama images licensed using [CC BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license), which is great for open-source projects. However, the images are of very varying quality and many of them would not be suitable for our project due to being very dark, low resolution or not having full 360 degrees view.

Is there any such open-source dataset available or has anyone devised a way to filter Mapillary/KartaView to curate the high-quality images?

Comment: In case you find no good answer here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/  could also be a suitable place to look for an answer.